# Getting Oculus Quest Mac Address through c++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, oculus, oculusquest

I've been trying to get the Mac Address from an Oculus Quest 2, at first i found the FGenericPlatformMisc::GetMacAddress, and implemented that on a Blueprint Function Library exposing that as a Blueprint. Worked getting my windows mac address, but when i try to use this in a oculus build returns nothing. I know that this function is deprecated and not reliable on all platforms, so someone know some way to get the mac from android / oculus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oculus runs Android 7+, so my guess would be that Oculus apps would be deliberately restricted from accessing it.  From [the Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-addresses):

> MAC addresses are globally unique, not user-resettable, and survive factory resets. For these reasons, to protect user privacy, on Android versions 6 and higher, access to MAC addresses is restricted to system apps. Third-party apps can't access them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think your guess is right, and i should've read the android docs